# Is a JRE needed when using Freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker, template-engine

I'm fairly new to using Freemarker, so my understanding admittedly isn't the best. From what I am able to tell, we use .ftl files which are templates that can interface with struts and other libraries. The content of the page is generated on the server (which has a JVM) and is then served as an HTML view on the client side. With that being said, I was previously under the impression that a JRE would need to be present on the client side for these applications to work. Having said that, I accessed the pages from a laptop without a JRE/JDK and they loaded without an issue. My question is if my finding is correct, that the client side does not need to have a JRE for the applications to work. I'd like to update our codebase from Java 7 to 8, but only if it won't infringe on the users needing to update Java versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, ftl templates don't "go back to the server, perform the method called in the respective Java class, prepare the view, and then send this to the client". The ftls are processed server-side and then the client gets a rendered html. If you use Struts with ftls then you need a server running a JVM with your Struts application in order for the htmls to be rendered.
The rendered htmls do not require a server because they're the result of the ftl processing. But again you need the server for that htmls to be rendered with the latest information on every request.
Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: I found it hard to describe what I meant, but what you assumed is what I meant. Our servers all run on JDK 1.8, so they serve the content without an issue. I was just curious if client side needed a JRE, but you answered that for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @jdhurricanes In that case, the client does not need Java at all :) Just a browser. 
You should upvote and mark this answer as correct if it answered your question. Cheers!

Comment: Done. Whenever I hit 15 reputation, I'll go back and upvote your answer. Thanks again. :)